# php-mysqli insert_id returns 0 instead of last id when object call is switched from static call

Tags: php, linux, database, oop, mysqli

I have been resurrecting an old project for new uses and running it on new PHP versions has resulted in this error:

> **Deprecated: Non-static** method Database::connect() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **/home/user/public_html/app/models/mainmodel.php** on line **108**

So, I went through finding old code that looks like this

```
$db = Database::connect();
$db->query("INSERT INTO users (userId) values ('1')");
```

and I turned them into

```
$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$db->query("INSERT INTO users (userId) values ('1')");
```

After that change, it has been working beautifully with the exception of the following

```
function save(){
  $db = Database::connect();
  if($this->id == 0){
    //Insert New
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `entities` (`active`) VALUES ('1')");
    $this->id = $db->last();
  }else{
    $db->query("UPDATE entities SET
                                   active = '" . $this->active . "',
                                   modified = now()
                                   WHERE id = '" . $this->id . "';");
  }
  return $this->id;
}
```

Which when I modify results in this

```
function save(){
  $db = new Database();
  $db->connect();
  if($this->id == 0){
    //Insert New
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `entities` (`active`) VALUES ('1')");
    $this->id = $db->last();
  }else{
    $db->query("UPDATE entities SET
                                   active = '" . $this->active . "',
                                   modified = now()
                                   WHERE id = '" . $this->id . "';");
  }
  return $this->id;
}
```

However now this line no longer works

```
$this->id = $db->last();
```

A var_dump of $this->id shows that it is being set to int(0) which does not happen when I use Database::connect() and the entry is being inserted

As a test, I put the following in my code to test

```
function save(){
  $dbconn = new mysqli ($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
  if($dbconn->connect_error){
    die('Connection Error (' . $dbconn->connect_errono . ') ' . $dbconn->connect_error);
  }

  if($this->id == 0){
    //Insert New
    $dbconn->query("INSERT INTO `entities` (`active`) VALUES ('1')");
    $this->id = $dbconn->last();
  }else{
    $dbconn->query("UPDATE entities SET
                                   active = '" . $this->active . "',
                                   modified = now()
                                   WHERE id = '" . $this->id . "';");
  }
  return $this->id;
}
```

This worked and did not return int(0).

For reference, here is my database class:

```
class Database extends mysqli {
    private static $db;
    public $results;

    public function __construct() {
      if(parent::__construct(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, NULL, NULL)) {
        return $this;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    public function connect($host = DB_HOST, $user = DB_USER, $pass = DB_PASS, $db = DB_NAME, $port = NULL, $socket = NULL) {
      if (!isset(self::$db)) {
        self::$db = new Database;
      }
      return self::$db;
    }

    public function query($str) {
      $this->results = mysqli_query(self::$db, $str);
      if($this->results===false) {
        echo $this->mysqli_error();
      }
      else
        return $this->results;
    }

    function last() {
            return $this->insert_id;
    }

final private function __clone() {}
}
```

Finally PHP and MySQL versions:

```
PHP Version: 5.6.40
MySQL Version: 5.6.43
```

I fear the issue exists in my database class extension, but cannot see exactly the problem, can someone help?

Comment: You say it doesn't return `int(1)`, is the row actually being created though?

Comment: When I call this via `Database::connect()` first, it works without fault (except the deprecated error) and returns the correct `int(1)` or whatever the last `AUTO_INCREMENT` id was. As soon as I change it to `$db = new Database();` it returns `int(0)`. Is this possibly an async issue?

Comment: Is a row in the database created when you use the non-static class method?

Comment: Yes, just the insert_id is not returned. I ended up getting my answer on reddit, the issue was the query was running procedural and was not updating insert_id on the object as it was procedural. I posted the answer below, but cannot accept until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Props to /u/bobbykjack on /r/PHPhelp for finding the problem.

The issue is the query function was using procedural calls vs object method which caused the object not to update the insert_id variable.

Old Code:

```
public function query($str) {
  $this->results = mysqli_query(self::$db, $str);
  if($this->results===false) {
    echo $this->mysqli_error();
  }
  else
    return $this->results;
}
```

New Code:

```
public function query($str) {
  $this->results = parent::query($str);
  if($this->results===false) {
    echo $this->mysqli_error();
  }
  else
    return $this->results;
}
```

I'm also looking into the purpose of this Database class since it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose, that your class Database doesn't have the property insert_id and maybe the class hasn't to have it, because insert_id is the property of **mysqli-object**.
See:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, user, pass, database_name); //create new mysqli object
$query = "write your own INSERT query";
$mysqli->query($query); //execute query
$last_id = $mysqli->insert_id; //get the last id of the row
```

Read examples attentively in the official manual:
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php